# Error creating Azure Function via Azure CLI in Azure DevOps YML pipeline task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-cli

I'm running the following Azure CLI command in an Azure DevOps yaml and it fails, but the same command works fine when run in a local console.

```
az functionapp create --name myapp-nightly-webhook --resource-group myapp-nightly --consumption-plan-location australiaeast --functions-version 3 --os-type Windows --runtime dotnet --storage-account myappnightlywebhook
```

Although it succeeds in the local console, it does return the following warnings:

> --runtime-version is not supported for --runtime dotnet. Dotnet version is determined by --functions-version. Dotnet version will be 3.1 for this function app.

> Application Insights "lightning-nightly-webhook" was created for this Function App. You can visit https://portal.azure.com/#resource/subscriptions/snip/resourceGroups/lightning-nightly/providers/microsoft.insights/components/myapp-nightly-webhook/overview to view your Application Insights component

I was wondering why it was returning the first warning (I'm not using the --runtime-version switch in my command) and whether that was making the task fail.

The DevOps task (AzureCLI@2) log shows:

> 2020-09-24T05:23:42.2169333Z az : --runtime-version is not supported for --runtime dotnet. Dotnet version is determined by --functions-version.
> 2020-09-24T05:23:42.2180924Z Dotnet version will be 3.1 for this function app.
> 2020-09-24T05:23:42.2181694Z At D:\a_temp\azureclitaskscript1600924977406_inlinescript.ps1:5 char:3
> 2020-09-24T05:23:42.2182456Z +   az functionapp create --name myapp-qa-webhook --resource-group  ...
> 2020-09-24T05:23:42.2183553Z +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 2020-09-24T05:23:42.2184379Z     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (--runtime-versi...s function app.:String) [], RemoteException
> 2020-09-24T05:23:42.2185073Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this pipeline

```yaml
trigger: none
pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'rg-the-code-manual'
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az functionapp create --name myapp-nightly-webhook-1 --resource-group TheCodeManual --consumption-plan-location australiaeast --functions-version 3 --os-type Windows --runtime dotnet --storage-account storageaccountthecobfaf'
```

I got warnings but the whole pipeline succeeded:
[image]

Can you compare this with your pipeline?

You can also remove `--runtime dotnet` to get rid of this warning. For that configuration you will get this

[image]